# Який діалект, котрий [найбільше] зрівняв родовий множини?

Tags: іменники, родовий-відмінок

Для порівняння нижньолужицька всюди по сутї [зрівняла](//en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Lower_Sorbian/Grammar/Declension_of_nouns) з *-ow* — український відповідник — *-ів*, в декотрих позіціях — *-їв*: *ryba → rybow*, *duša → dušow*, *słowo → słowow* ітд.

Стандартна українська в цьому досить розмашиста.

Чоловічий рід зазвичай і маєʼ *-ів*:

- Тип на **-ŭ*: сыновъ* → *синів*.
- Тип на **-ĭ*: *гостьи* → *гостей*; однак за витягом в пунктї нижче можна побачити, що декотрі діалекти мають *гостїв*. Також можна згадати винятки як *звірїв*, *зятїв*.
- Тип на **-ŏ*, мякий варіант, *отьць* → *отців*; але *конь* → *коней*, що набув флексію з попереднього пункту, хоча говірки знають про *конїв*.

  > Окремі іменники ч. р. в досліджуваних діалектних масивах замість передбаченої літературною нормою флексії *-еǐ* Р. в. мн. мають фонетично видозмінене закінчення **-овъ* давніх **-ǔ*-основ; пор. з лемківської говірки: *бонкы літают коло конів* [СЛГ: 18], а також спостережені паралелі: *мáли двóйе кóн′ів* (Жашковичі Ів), *д′íти* / *ни гон′íте мойíх гóс′т′ів* (Губин Лк).
  >
  > <sub>[Лемківський діалект у загальноукраїнському контексті](http://catalog.library.tnpu.edu.ua/naukovi_zapusku/stydia_metod/studia27.pdf) / Укладачі Панцьо С.Є.,
  > Cвистун Н.О. // Studia methodologica. – Випуск 27. – Тернопіль: Редакційно-видавничий
  > відділ ТНПУ ім.В.Гнатюка, 2009. – 158 с</sub>

  Середнїй рід повторив: *поль* → *полїв*, *поль* [досї існує](//goroh.pp.ua/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BC%D1%96%D0%BD%D0%B0/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5#25821), особливо в західних діалектах, але, за своїм досвідом вважаю, не є поширеною в стандартній. Для порівняння, *морів* вже не маєʼ алтернатівної форми. І водночас не повторив, наприклад: [**ajьcь*](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Slavic/aj%D1%8Cce#Declension) → *яєць*, хоча нестандартий вжиток [*яйцїв*](//google.com.ua/search?lr=-lang_ru&q=%22%D1%8F%D0%B9%D1%86%D1%96%D0%B2%22) цїлком собі ся зустрїчаїть.

  Можна також окремо згадати про [наросток **-ьje*](/q/762/585), котрий теж зазвичай без закінчїннь в родовому, але гинколи буваєʼ з *-ів*: *відкриттїв*, *подвірʼїв*, *життїв* ітд.
- Тип на **-ŏ*, твердий варіант: *городъ* → *городів*; але цього разу середній пішов гиншим шляхом: *селъ* → *сіл*. Не бачу причин, аби якийсь діалект маєʼ однакові форми і тут.
- Підтип на **-n*: *каменъ* → *каменїв*, *дьнъ* → *днїв*. Виняток хиба що слова з [наростком *-ан*](/a/7268/585): *киян*, *галичан*.

  Середнїй, можна вважати, теж зберїг стару форму, хоча це можить бути і частково вплив твердого типа на **-ŏ*.

Середній, з того що не згадано вище:

- Підтип на **-s*: *словесъ* → *слів*, тобто долучив ся до твердого типу на **-ŏ*, хоча можна зазначити, що [наросток *-ес-*](/a/7031/585) місцями зберїгся, наприклад ві слові *словесний*. Тут наросток *-ів* можу знайти хіба що з *-ес-*, наприклад [*словесів*](//google.com.ua/search?lr=-lang_ru&q=%22%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%96%D0%B2%22).
- Підтип на **-nt*: *ягнѧтъ* → *ягнят*. Мої швидкі пошуки щодо *-ів* нічого не привели.

Жїночий, тут це переважно без закінчїннь, хоча можна згадати:

- Підтип на **-r*: *матеръ* → *матерїв*; волосне, це єдине слово, котре знаю.
- Тип на **-ā*, що мякий і твердий, [мають варіяції](///q/2762/585) з *-ів*: *легень* ~ *легенїв*, *баб* ~ *бабів*, *губ* ~ *губів*, *старост* ~ *старостів* ітд.
- Тип на **-ū*: *букъвъ* → *букв*, *цьркъвъ* → *церков*. Як не дивно, але форми [*буквів*](//google.com.ua/search?lr=-lang_ru&q=%22%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B2%22) і [*церквів*](//google.com.ua/search?lr=-lang_ru&q=%22%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B2%22) теж цїлком існують. Так писав наприклад [Грушевський](//google.com.ua/search?q=site:hrushevsky.nbuv.gov.ua+%22%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B2%22&lr=-lang_ru). Хоча особисто такого не натряпяв свідомо, тому для мене це дещо новинка.

Можна помітити, що, на першого позір, щонайменше переважають дві форми: без закінчїння і *-ів*. Чи є діалект, котрий дійшов до десь такого само, що і нижньолужицька. Якщо немаʼ — то який найближче дійшов?